# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I fix this? I have been trying, but whatever I change makes my pictures move.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pics').masonry({
        columnWidth: 320,
        itemSelector: '.item1',
        isFitWidth: true,
    }).imagesLoaded(function() {
        $(this).masonry('reload');
    });

});
```

Comment: By not trying to call `imagesLoaded`.

Comment: I think your question needs more thought.  Think about how a reader will see the question.  You need to be clearer where the error is appearing.  You could also provide additional context on the question.

Answer (score 0):

http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#upgrading-from-v2

> imagesLoaded no longer included, but is still recommended.

You can get it from http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/